# When are spectral values a pole of the resolvent?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, semigroup-of-operators

Let $(T_t)_{\geq 0}$ be a $C_0$-semigroup on a Banach space $X$ with the generator $A.$

> What are some conditions sufficient for $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ to be a pole of resolvent?

I'm looking for conditions on the semigroup or $A.$

**Background:** I'm trying to prove some stability results for $(T_t)_{t \geq 0}$ and it seems to me that not knowing beforehand that the spectral bound $s(A)$ is a pole of $R(\cdot, A)$ is a roadblock in most cases. Hence I'm looking for conditions that ensure it is a pole, so I can somehow try to prove those conditions.

Comment: To be a pole, it has to be isolated.  And when a singularity is isolated, there aren't many possibilities.  Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Yes, I know a pole needs to be an isolated spectral value. My question is whether there are some conditions on $A$ which makes an isolated spectral value a pole.

Comment: What is an example of when the spectral value is isolated, but the singularity is not a pole?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: A typical example is the Volterra integral operator on, say, $C([0,1])$: its spectrum consists of $0$ only, but $0$ is an essential singularity of the resolvent.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One sufficient condition for this is that the semigroup is eventually compact. This is proved in Corollary V.3.2 in the book by [Engel & Nagel](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA296&lpg=PA296&dq=A+first+stability+concept,+called+uniform+exponential+stability,+has+already+been+introduced+in+Definition+I.3.11.&source=bl&ots=2RWc1D9N3F&sig=ACfU3U0a66voV0zR39yYQAQZs-Kd3Vj5HQ&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXosuv5PPoAhUNK7kGHSxeBS4Q6AEwAHoECAsQLA#v=onepage&q=A%20first%20stability%20concept%2C%20called%20uniform%20exponential%20stability%2C%20has%20already%20been%20introduced%20in%20Definition%20I.3.11.&f=false).

Section 5.8 of the book by [Taylor](https://books.google.de/books/about/Introduction_to_Functional_Analysis.html?id=JP5QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) is a good source for other conditions.

I'm aware of $2$ sufficient conditions in the case $X$ is a **Banach lattice** and the resolvent set of $A$ is non-empty:

$1.)\, u \in E_+$ and $D(A^n)\subseteq E_u$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

$2.)\, u \in E_+$ and $T(t_0)E\subseteq E_u$ for some $t_0>0.$

The proof of these two can be found in Corollary 2.4 and 2.5 of a paper by [D. Daners and J. Glück](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/role-of-domination-and-smoothing-conditions-in-the-theory-of-eventually-positive-semigroups/3E99701B86D21FDD8D394AEEFB8B9F9D).

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Can you also have a look at my [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3647967/limit-of-resolvent-in-terms-of-limit-of-semigroup)?

Answer (score -2):

A $C_0$ semigroup $S(t)$ on a Banach space is uniformly bounded in operator norm near $0$. That's enough to be able to prove there there is a $\rho > 0$ such that $e^{-\rho t}S(t)$ is a bounded $C_0$ semigroup. A bounded $C_0$ semigroup $S(t)$ has a generator $A$ with resolvent
$$
       -(A-\lambda I)^{-1}= \int_0^{\infty}e^{t(A-\lambda I)}dt=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda t}S(t)dt.
$$
That gives you a bound on the resolvent in terms of the uniform bound on $e^{-\rho t}S(t)$, and the bound is applicable for $\Re\lambda > \rho$. If there is a pole for the resolvent on the line $\Re\lambda=\rho$, then it is a pole of order $1$ because of the bound that is obtained by the above integral.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. I wanted sufficient conditions for a spectral value to be a pole, I already knew that if it is a pole, it would be a simple pole. What I'm interested is in, what are the sufficient conditions for it to be a pole?

Comment: @Mark : Where do you expect a pole to be? You can't prove the resolvent exists outside of the open right half-plane, and you can prove the entire right half-plane is in the resolvent set. So you can't prove holomorphic behavior in a neighborhood of any point in the closed left half-plane. Any existence proof of holomorphic behavior gives a simply connected region. I've never seen any result that shows the resolvent exists on a non-simply-connected region. So that would be the first hurdle to overcome.